# Get indices of duplicate columns only

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following array:

```
np.array([1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5])
```

I would like to get the indices of the duplicate values only, so the output would look like:

```
np.array([3,4,6])
```

This is so basic I feel like I am missing some simple numpy command but I cannot seem to find a simple non-looping solution. Anyone have any ideas?

Ideally the solution would be efficient (no looping) and scale to multiple dimensions.

A multidimensional case could look like this: Given,

```
[[3,2,1,1], [2,2,1,1]]
```

It should return

```
[3]
```

Since there is a duplicate `[1,1]` at index 3

Comment: Questions: 1. Is the input always sorted? 2. What are duplicates in multiple dimensions? Duplicate vectors/tensors, or single-element duplicates?

Comment: 1) The input will not always be sorted 2) a duplicate in multiple dimensions may be for instance: [[3,2,1,1], [2,2,1,1]] which should return a single 3 (we have a duplicate [1,1] at index 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the unique values using `np.unique` and the rest are duplicates (This solution does **NOT** require your array to be sorted. You can easily extend this to multi-dimensional. Please provide a sample input/output for multi-dimension and I will update it):

```
np.delete(np.arange(a.size), np.unique(a,return_index=True)[1])
```

output:

```
[3 4 6]
```

**UPDATE**: Per OP's update on multi-dimensional case:

```
at = a.T
b = np.ascontiguousarray(at).view(np.dtype((np.void, at.dtype.itemsize * at.shape[1])))
np.delete(np.arange(b.size), np.unique(b,return_index=True)[1])
```

Or similarly and easier suggested by @Adrix in comments:

```
np.delete(np.arange(a.shape[1]), np.unique(a,return_index=True, axis=1)[1])
```

output:

```
[3]
```

Comment: Updated with multidimensional case

Comment: Ah, different than I imagined the desired output for multi-dimensional would be. Added the extension to cover it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to combine np.where and np.diff (duplicates are items which difference equals zero):

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5])
>>> np.where(np.diff(arr) == 0)[0] + 1
array([3, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
[i for i in np.arange(len(x)) if i not in np.unique(x, return_index=True)[1]]
```

```
[3, 4, 6]
```

Admittedly, the filtering part can definitely be improved.